# Firebase Cloud Messaging notRegistered Error but the Token is the same (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the error 'notRegistered' when i try to send notification to chrome. I checked the current token and it is the same. Also the function `onTokenRefreshed()` is not called so i am assuming token is not changed.

The error I get occurs when users remove the notification permission on chrome and give permission again.

What you think about this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m facing this issue with android client. It has suddenly started happening in prod, roughly 25% of HTTP GCMs are failing with NotRegistered.

Comment: did you find any solution? @sandeepd

Comment: Nope. Google Support asked me to upgrade to FCM since I'm using other Firebase products. They recommend to use FCM over GCM if you're using any other Firebase product. But this might be specific to Android, no idea on web.